# How do I render rich text to an image?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtext

I'm trying to create a rich text DataGridViewCell.  I can host a RichTextBox as the editing control, but when the cell isn't in editing mode I need to paint the rich text myself.  I don't want to parse the text - I just need an equivalent of Graphics.DrawString that works with rich text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's an example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812425) where you can add a print feature to the richtextbox. It's basically just copying the rich text to the Graphics object used for printing. I think you could modify this to use your own graphics object instead, and basically "print" to an image.

Edit:

[Here's a post](http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/523657-c-printing-content-richtextbox-image-wysiwyg-mode) where someone seems to have modified the print code for creating an image.

Comment: This is the answer I would have given. I've used a similar approach with a custom drawn treeview, in order to double buffer it, and it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a solution within WinForms that can do that for you. The best approach here is probably to use the `RichTextBox` for both plain rendering and editing, and just lock it (set `Locked` to true) when not in edit mode.

Comment: The editing control of a DataGridViewCell isn't displayed when the cell isn't in edit mode - I need to be able to render the text even when I don't have access to an onscreen RichTextBox instance.

Comment: print to a custom graphics device context built upon an image. That's a native part of winforms.